# Контроль авторизаций на прокси-сервере Squid

Tags: авторизация, прокси, логирование, squid

Здравствуйте. Покажите, каким образом я могу контролировать факт авторизации на прокси **Squid**. В `squid3\access.log` я вижу уже непосредственную активность пользователя, а хотелось бы отслеживать именно факт успешной авторизации.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так-как авторизация в squid осуществляется при помощи внешней программы, которая со своего стандартного входа считывает "username password" и возвращает "OK" или "ERR", то самым легким способом будет оборачивание нужной Вам программы в скрипт, который будет принимать "username password"-строку, передавать ее по назначению, делать запись в log-файл и возвращать squid-у результат выполнения. Примерный скрипт для auth_param basic:

squid.conf:

```
auth_param basic /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth.script /etc/squid/passwd.file
```

/usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth.script:

```
#!/bin/bash
AUTH_DATE=`date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"`
while read; do
    AUTH_STRING="$REPLY"
    USERNAME=`echo ${AUTH_STRING} | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
    RES=`echo ${AUTH_STRING} | /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd`
    echo -e $AUTH_DATE'\tusername:'${USERNAME}'\t\tlogin result:\t'$RES >> /var/log/squid/auth.log
    echo $RES
done
```

Изменил скрипт.

Comment: Я немного изменил инструкцию под squid3, однако после авторизации "тишина". Логи появляются, факт авторизации фиксируется, но сам прокси перестаёт отдавать трафик. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @soulruins: Что-нть в логах сквида появляется?

Comment: @soulruins: Исправил скрипт - был не совсем корректный способ чтения из stdin. Попробуйте этот вариант

Comment: да, теперь всё работает! Но, как я понимаю, если сеанс уже открыт, т.е. я прошел авторизацию на прокси, например дома, то если я в это время авторизируюсь из другого места, то данный факт зафиксирован не будет (в логах я его не вижу)? Можно ли добавить в лог ещё и IP? :-)

Comment: @soulruins: не уверен, что это возможно.

Comment: хорошо, в любом случае спасибо. Попробую теперь связать  `auth.log` и `access.log`, на выходе, надеюсь, получится нужный мне контроль доступа.